# Remove index.php when access using ip address

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I uploaded codeigniter project on server.Removing index.php from URL is not working. I access it using IP address. like http://ip address/

Below is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I tried all possible solutions found on google. but not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow some step:

1. goto application/config/config.php :
   replace `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`
   and 
   `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';`
2. enable rewrite mode by
    `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
   then
   `service apache2 restart`
3. if you'd like, you can use the following .htaccess file.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

in httpd.conf, edit or delete "index.php":

```
<IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule
```

Then in htaccess, add this:

Options -Indexes

Comment: I can not finf httpd.conf only apache2.conf is there in /etc/apache2

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in .htaccess. Hope this work.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: Open config.php and replace with blank
   $config['index_page'] = "";

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.htaccess` as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Then open  `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf` file and find `<Directory "/var/www/html">` with in this find and set `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.