# CodeIgniter .htaccess not working on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I just moved my project to EC2 and I can't get my .htaccess to work properly for removing index.php. When attempting to access my website, I receive the following error message - "The requested URL /nutrition/auth/login was not found on this server". I have tried numerous .htaccess files and switched my uri_protocol back and forth between 'REQUEST_URI' and 'AUTO'.

The folder structure of where my project is located is /var/www/html/nutrition/

I have verified that mod_rewrite is enabled. It shows as a loaded module when I view phpinfo.

I have set AllowOverride All in httpd.conf:

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

base_url in config.php is set to: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://<ip_address>/nutrition/';`

index_page in config.php is set to: `$config['index_page'] = '';`

uri_protocol in config.php is set to: `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

.htaccess file (located in Nutrition folder) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nutrition/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I know this is a common question that I'm sure you're tired of answering, but I have tried numerous offered solutions to no avail. Thanks for any help you all can give.

I have resolved the issue. There was a third option to set AllowOverride All in httpd.conf. After updating that, .htaccess started working.

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` for that Virtual Host? Try removing `RewriteBase /nutrition/`

Comment: @ishegg `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html` in httpd.conf. Same result after removing that line from .htaccess.

Comment: @DerekMorgan can you check this link might be it helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46089887/remove-index-php-when-access-using-ip-address/46092639#46092639

Comment: RewriteBase in my case was needed to exist. Thought it's your case too, but now noticed you have this line. No more ideas, but this line iis OK.

Comment: @VijaySharma Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. I still get the same result.

Comment: @DerekMorgan did you able to load home page means default page?

Comment: @VijaySharma I am unable to load the home page - I get a 404 error.

Comment: @DerekMorgan  did your file name first letter is capital?

Comment: Means controller file name

Comment: @VijaySharma Yes, all of my class filenames start with a capital letter.

Comment: @DerekMorgan  did you put index.php in url n tried?

Comment: @VijaySharma Yes, the site loads with index.php in the url.

Comment: @DerekMorgan  if you dont mind can you share one controller file code so i can check in local?

Comment: @VijaySharma Sure, here's a very basic controller - https://codeshare.io/5QOldL

Comment: I have resolved the issue. There was a third option to set `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf. After updating that, my .htaccess started working. Thanks for the help @VijaySharma